# How to synchronize the map in Rviz and Stage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to All,

I am new to ROS. I am doing the navigation simulation based on the package of "navigation_stage". I replace the default map with mine and generate the .world file. But when I run the simulation, the maps in Rviz and that in Stage are not synchronous (they are not in the same coordinate). I notice the size, orientation can be adjusted in the .world file. But I do not know how to set the values for them.

Is any one know about this?  Thanks in advance.

Fangwen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173965/how-to-synchronize-the-map-in-rviz-and-stage/) by [Cole](https://answers.ros.org/users/18875/cole/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Itay.H](https://answers.ros.org/users/23734/itay.h/) on 2015-09-01**:
Hi,

I am having the same problem.
Have you solved this yet?

**Comment by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on 2016-01-17**:
i also need help in doing the same thing plz can someone help us all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently ran in the same problem and summarized all I found out in [this post](https://medium.com/@ivangavran/ros-creating-world-file-from-existing-yaml-5b553d31cc53#.88e8vmwuh)
There are two main points:

1. align coordinate system, taking into account that .yaml origin gives coordinates of lower left point in the image, while .worlds's pose gives coordinates of the centre of the map.
2. add a black border around the image, because otherwise it would be trimmed by Stage

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3